# HoughlinesP parameters "threshold" and "minLineLength"

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am using HoughLinesP function in OpenCV. After reading the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines), I am confused regarding the necessity of two parameters "threshold" and "minLineLength".
Documentation says:

> threshold – Accumulator threshold parameter. Only those lines are
> returned that get enough votes ( >threshold ).
>
> minLineLength – Minimum line length. Line segments shorter than that are rejected.

Isn't one of them redundant? Isn't the number of votes a line gets is equal to number of pixels it contains? Given that "minLineLength" specifies which lines to reject, what is the use of "threshold"? Am I missing something here. A clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps this will help: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Comment: @QED - Thanks. I have read this but It didn't clarify me about the two parameters I mentioned. I want to know what is the difference between "threshold" and "minLineLength". It sounds to me that both the parameters specify the minimum line length. Is that correct?

Comment: it seems as though for the standard method you may be correct as it doesn't have that parameter. However the prob. method has two additional parameters  "minLinLength" and "maxLineGap" thus i can only conclude (guess) that in this case two lines can be joined together, thus the final length of the conjoined line may no longer be directly associated with the number of votes, as it consists of two lines + a "gap", where the gap may have no votes.  I would have to check the paper to be sure, but there is no reference in the doc.

Comment: From here it looks like the mismatch maybe becuase of random sampling: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV1011/macdonald.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clarifies it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the cells of accumulator are wide and there are many closely spaced short lines, then the count of accumulator would be high. The `min_line_length` would help solve such issues.

Hope this clarifies the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i read the documentation and how Randomized Hough Transform (will call it RHT) works and i have this idea, it might not be right though.

In  RHT not all the binary points are taken into consideration, right. That's why it is faster. So, `threshold` means in the accumulator how many votes needed to consider this (rho, theta) as a line, this is the easy one.

The second one is a little bit confusing, but here is my though, `minLineLength` might be the length of the line calculated from the points that voted for it. Meaning, if we have a 5 points to vote for a certain line and all these points are so close, then the `lineLength` will be short may be 5 pixels. On the other hand, if 3 points voted for another line and the points are far a part, then the `lineLength` is large may be 20 pixels.

So we can't consider the voting threshold to be equal to the lineLength because not all binary points are taken into the calculation.